# How to create image pyramid for GeoServer programmatically

Tags: geoserver

I try to create a tiled layer for my OpenLayers3 application. For the creation part I plan to use GDAL `gdal_retile.py` script. I've already tried it and it seems to work as I expected it to. Now I want to provide the resulting tiles as a layer to my OpenLayers application. Indeed (I guess like all programmers), I do not want to use GeoServer UI for this part and want to do it compeletly programmatically. Unfortunatelly, official [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.x/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html) only provides the way how to do it through UI and does not provide corresponding REST API. I do not want to read the whole GeoServer documentation from ground up, just to learn at the very end, that it's imposible to do this task through API. So, I'm asking this question in advance with a hope, that someone can justify, that we can do all this - create a tiled layers - just using GeoServer REST API and without touching its UI. And to be more concrete, I guess, I need these three operations, addressed in the documentation:

- creation of the coverage store by pointing at the directory containing the pyramid
- choosing a coverage, which will be named after the pyramid root directory
- publishing the layer, and then seting the layer parameter USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD to false to get better scalability

Comment: use the REST API to request an existing pyramid's settings and modify those files and send them back, then add your findings to the documentation.

Comment: @iant. Thanks! Unfortunattely, I don't quite understand what you mean. REST API is actually what I need and I do not know whether there is such an API for the above operations. And you are saying "use the REST API"...

Comment: you can fetch the details of any layer/store using the REST api which shows you the required parameters

Comment: Let's say I created a directory with tiles using gdal_retile.py script. Can you please advise, for example, how can I "create of the coverage store by pointing at the directory containing the pyramid" using REST API. This is the first operation implemented through GUI, as it is described here - http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.x/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html

Comment: Is there REST API for this very operation?

Comment: create it in the GUI and then use the REST API to see what the required file looks like - one of the fields will be directory name, change that and send it back

Comment: Please, let me stress it again - I do not want to use GeoServer GUI. What I want is to use solely its REST API. And in this very case, when we are talking about a specific operation (which of course can be done through GUI), I'm not even sure if there is a corresponding REST API in GeoServer, so that I could do the same programmatically.

Comment: And by the way, the documentation seems to be incorrect. The gdal_retile.py command sets bmpyramid as a target directory. But all the following commands refer to `bm_pyramid` and `pyramid` and never refer to `bmpyramid`. I find it really confusing, that they use the same word with so many variations.